# Js - Worker - importScript and polluting the context

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Im learning about Workers. I can use **importScripts** but, what is the context where the imported script is loaded?

If inside my Worker I executed:

*worker.js*

```
importScripts('embeed.js')

hello // contains "hello world"
self.hello // undefined
this.hello // undefined
```

*embeed.js*

```
const hello = "hello world"
```

In what context is **hello** saved? It is not in **self** and worker does not expose **window** so, How does it know about the **hello** variable? Is there some prototype chaining?

Comment: I belive it just runs the script in the position `importScripts` is placed in

Comment: I understand that but my question is about where or what context is used for saving the variable. In browser, if you do ´´´hello = 'hello'´´´ then you are saving the variable into the global scope, which is **window**. Running inside a worker, after importScript-ed, where are those variables defined in the script saved?

Comment: Try running logging 'this'. But I believe it's just the worker itself